# A stochastic model for cell division

Tags: probability, statistics

I am considering the following problem related to a statistical model of cell division.

Suppose we start out with sample points $x_1, \dots, x_N$, which are drawn from, say, a normal distribution $N(\mu=1, \sigma_1^2)$.

Then, randomly pick, say, a third of the samples. For each picked sample $x_i^\star$, we draw two samples from a second normal distribution $N(\mu=x_i^\star, \sigma_2^2)$ with $\sigma_2 << \sigma_1$. We then throw $x_i^\star$ away, but add the two newly drawn samples to the pool of samples.

The above may be iterated several times, simulating a cell division process with stochastic splitting of a considered protein for example.

I simulated this and found that, not very surprisingly, after $k$ stages, we end up with histograms resembling normal distributions. However, I could not find a way to predict the variance of this distribution based on our knowledge of the selection process and the means and variances of the two normal distributions. This would be the first step to better understand this mathematical model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the distribution is centered at first ($\mu=0$). Clearly the population is always centered. Suppose the variance is $\sigma_t^2$ after $t$ divisions. Then
$$
\sigma_{t+1}^2 = \frac{3}{4n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\mathbb E\left[\frac{2}{3}X_i^2 + \frac{1}{3}\left((X_i+\sigma_2Y_i)^2 + (X_i+\sigma_2Z_i)^2\right)\right]},
$$
where $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are independent standard Normal random variables. Simple algebra then yields $\sigma_{t+1}^2 = \sigma_t^2 + \frac{2}{3}\sigma_2^2$. Therefore, $\sigma_k^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \frac{2k}{3}\sigma_2^2$.

Comment: thank you! Could you please elaborate a bit on how you got to the big equation in the middle?

Comment: Sure. $2/3$ refers to those points that are not branched, and $1/3$ are points that are branched. Because one point gets two samples, we have two terms in the second term. Finally, the $3/4n$ term in front of the summation is the fact that after each division you have $4n/3$ points, where $n$ is the number of points in the last epoch.

Comment: Thank you again! Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with these kind of processes, but you do seem to be familiar with them. The more general question I was trying to answer is: Given a normal distribution $N(\mu=1, \sigma_1^2)$, what does the second distribution have to look like so that after each iteration, the result is the same distribution $N(\mu=1, \sigma_1^2)$ again?

Comment: I'm afraid that in your current model such stationarity cannot be achieved, as you deliberately introduced more variance at each iteration. The only thing I noticed is that the mean does not change, but the variance certainly increases.

Comment: On a side note, if you half your variance at each iteration you might be able to see that the entire population distribution will converge.